# How to use java plugin with buildSrc code

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, buildsrc

I'm trying to move the "make fat (aka. uber) jar" code I use from my root build.gradle.kts
file into a file in the `buildSrc` directory.  To that end I created a file `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/executableJar.kt`:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.file.DuplicatesStrategy
import org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskProvider
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.register

fun Project.makeExecutableJar (name: String, main: String?, sset: SourceSet) : TaskProvider<Jar>
{
    return tasks.register<Jar>(name) {
        dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
        archiveFileName.set("$name.jar")
        main?.let { manifest.attributes["Main-Class"] = it }
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE

        sset.allSource.forEach { println("==> Source: ${it.absolutePath}") }
        from(sset.output)

        from(sset.runtimeClasspath.filter {
            println("==> Include: ${it.name}")
            it.name.endsWith(".jar")}.map { zipTree(it) }
        )

    }
}
```

However, I get an "unresolved reference" in intJ for `configurations.runtimeClasspath`, which requires the java plugin.  So I added a few lines to `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, which now looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    java
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
```

But this does not solve the problem.  How can I access the java plugin features for stuff in `buildSrc`?  My best guess is that I need to include an explicit `dependency { implementation(...) }` for it, but, after searching maven and [the gradle plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=java), I
can't determine an url/ID string for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configurations.runtimeClasspath` is a generated [Gradle Kotlin DSL accessor](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#type-safe-accessors), and these are only available inside `*.gradle.kts` files.

Instead you'll have to access the configuration by the name, using [`ConfigurationContainer.getByName()`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html#getByName-java.lang.String-).

Conveniently, [`JavaPlugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6urrent/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.html) provides the name of the `runtimeClasspath` Configuration, so it can be imported and used directly (rather than using a 'magic' string).

```kotlin
// import JavaPlugin
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin

// (existing imports)
// import ...

fun Project.makeExecutableJar (name: String, main: String?, sset: SourceSet) : TaskProvider<Jar> {
    // access the runtimeClasspath configuration
    val runtimeClasspathConfiguration = configurations.named(JavaPlugin.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
    
    return tasks.register<Jar>(name) {
        dependsOn(runtimeClasspathConfiguration )
        // ...
    }
}
```